# Arrays of Object[]

Tags: java, arrays

Assign Object[] to Object[]

```
public TableDB(){
        model = new DefaultTableModel();

        table = new JTable(model){/*{ public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
            return editMode; //Disallow the editing of any cell
            }}*/;
        /*public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return Integer.class;
                default:
                    return Boolean.class;
        }}*/};
        addColumnFromDB();
        addDataFromDB();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        //model.addColumn("Name"); 
        //model.addColumn("Score"); 
        //
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);

    }

    public void addDataFromDB(){
        Object[] data = bl.getData();
        for(int i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
           model.addRow(data[i]); 
        }
    }
```

Other class

```
public Object[] getData()
{
    Object[] data ={"a"};
    return data;
}
```

Compiler says "no suitable method found for addRow(java.lang.Object)" but i use Object[]
The problem is in `model.addRow(data[i]);`

Comment: What's the signature for `addRow()`?

Comment: It 's declared on 
DefaultTableModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be doing the below code, if you are, as I assume, using `DefaultTableModel`

```
public void addDataFromDB(){
    Object[] data = bl.getData();
    model.addRow(data);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) then you need to provide the whole array, not just an element of it. So it should be like this: `model.addRow(data);`

Answer (score 0):

The method [addRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) needs an Object[]. You give him a Object.
Try `model.addRow(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Signature of addRow method is `addRow(Object[])` so you need to pass an array of Objects rather than individual Object. Try

```
model.addRow(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is specification of `addRow`

> addRow

```
public void addRow(Vector rowData)
```

Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.

```
Parameters:
```

`rowData` - optional data of the row being added
addRow

```
public void addRow(Object[] rowData)
```

Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.
`Parameters`:
`rowData` - optional data of the row being added

and you are passing

```
 model.addRow(data[i]);
```

but it requires `Object[]`